# What Oauth2 flow to choose for this particular situation?

Tags: oauth2, authentication

I have a single page app (call it `Collector`) on my server and would like my users to have a customizable list of links like :

`facebook.com/get_my_latest_posts_about_cats
github.com/get_my_comments_for_repo_LinuxKernel
anynews.com/get_my_soccer_news`

They can add new/remove links into their link dialog box every time.

So what I am trying to do is to relieve the user of the pain to login every time in order to get data from the `facebook,github,news ...` server.

Of course, the first time the user clicks on any of his links he will receive the respective login page of the link (e.g. `facebook.com/get_my_latest_posts_about_cats` -> `facebook.com/login`) but afterwards I'll use their access token along with refresh token stored in my `Collector database` so that they won't have to write their pass and username every next time.

My question :

(Please tell me if at least it makes any sense, so that I don't get any false ideas about how this works)

- I don't know what flow should I implment my `Collector` web app because I'm doing this for the first time, and the whole `authentication process` is also new for me, so which one actually would fit my needs ?
- I thought about [user agent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_user_agent_oauth_flow.htm) flow, becaue I don't think I want to store the `client_secret` in my `Collector` database.